# Draw and Move Line with Mouse Move Event

Tags: c#

I'm able to draw vertical line anywhere on the screen with following code:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);
[DllImport("User32.dll")]

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // DRAWING
    IntPtr desktopPtr = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
    Graphics f = Graphics.FromHdc(desktopPtr);

    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 111, 0));
    f.DrawLine(pen, this.Location.X, this.Location.Y, this.Location.X, 100);

    f.Dispose();
    ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, desktopPtr);
  }
```

Above sample code draw the vertical line on coordinates where form is open but however this line disappear when i move anything over it (cursor, form, etc).

I want to keep this line until application is closed.

Next what i Want to achieve is make this line movable with mouse move events. Is it possible?

Comment: Probably the simplest way would be to store the coordinates of the mouse in a list when the MouseMove event is triggered, then trigger the OnPaint event an redraw the line there with the saved coordinates.

Comment: Since you won't know why or when the screen will refresh you may try to use a Timer to redraw the line every, maybe 100 ms.. For th movement you first need to define the user interface!